# PHP long polling, without excessive database access

Tags: php

I've always enjoyed the idea of long polling; on my development server I've played with various notification / new post systems, each using javascript to hold a connection and 'wait' for some sort of response. I've always had an issue with many implementations of this, they all involve repetitively polling the mySQL server to check for new rows.

A dedicated server for long polling requests is a possibility, but it seems very wasteful to continuously poll (around ever 3 seconds seems common) a database server for every client. Its a huge waste of resources for something that is relatively insignificant.

Is there a batter way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your specific problem is that you're trying to avoid notifying events through a database, you should probably be looking at using shared memory or semaphores.

Instead of continuously polling the database, you would instead monitor the shared memory.  When something writes to the db (I'm assuming some sort of message queue), you can flag the event via the shared memory. The listening code would detected this, and only then establish a db connection to retrieve the message.  Alternatively, you could use shared memory to entirely replace the use of the database.

The reference for the php semaphore and shared memory functions is here - http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php

Answer (score 4):

I would use some nosql to notify there is new data. [Redis](http://redis.io) has [pub/sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) and a [blocking list](http://redis.io/commands/brpop).

You can also use, for example, memcache and create a new key when the data is available.

Comment: Thats actually an excellent idea. I had completely forgotten about memcache, as not many of the applications I develop would benefit from it. Reading the variables from the memcache would certainly be faster, thanks for that!

Comment: Would you please provide an example? I never used it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets)

...

When it's actually fully supported ;)

Comment: Its not to much the server polling thats an issue, rather the storing and retrieval of data on the server side.

Comment: Then I'd definitely go with seppo0010's suggestion. Guess that's what I get for just glancing over the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

data cache, I like the one from Zend Server, it dramatically reduced pulling from database

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you Insert or update your database create a cache for that field of the database. You can use any simple PHP based cache (http://hycus.com/2011/03/31/hcache-a-cache-system-for-php/).

Then you can poll that cache continuously using JQUERY.

Answer (score -1):

Can look into having a flash movie in the background that maintains a continuous connection with the server using sockets. Java also supports sockets so can also be a java applet embedded in your page.

Comment: Thats nothing to do with what I asked.