# JQuery | Ajax | Continuously check for changes in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, database

I'm creating a social media site, should I use a loop in javascript that continually loops, updating information on the page? Such as a status of friends (eg friends or pending). I feel like a loop would be rather overkill though. Should I setup timers in javascript that check every 5 seconds for changes in the database? Then updates the DOM with jquery. Thank you alot. Hopefully you don't think this question is too generic, I don't see any need to show code. It's theoretical talk. Thanks again.

Should I use node.js? Or websockets? Keep in mind, I plan for this site to have unlimited growing potential. What does facebook use?

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, you may want to try a push notification service. This is good if you have multiple server calls. That way, rather than check for multiple updates using different functions on the server, you call a single function that checks if there is anything that needs updating, and let the client know whats new. If you're only making a single call, using a timer in Javascript is fine for doing this. Just make sure that it isn't returning a lot of information if it doesn't need to.

Comment: It's your call, but I would think using a 5-second timer would result in a LOT of database hits if the site were to have any decent number of users.  Eventually, too many database requests would result in slowdowns or data denial.  You could always do a single database lookup every time the page is refreshed.

Comment: You can also look into WebSockets and frameworks that implement these like Socket.IO

Comment: Look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758379/whats-the-best-practice-for-php-to-continuously-check-for-changes-in-the-databa) may useful

Comment: A loop isn't very useful for sending something every n seconds. An interval would be better, however, even better than that would be a setTimeout so that if it takes longer than n seconds, it doesn't start to pile up.

Comment: Uses a database trigger for insertions on the table and have server-side program forward the changes to the front-end using WebSockets.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Is a push notification service or a websocket faster/better?

Comment: @master565 Is a push notification service or a websocket faster/better?

Comment: Websocket is a newer technology, but I'm not sure which is better. It's probably a case by case basis, and I'm not enough of an expert on these technologies to give you a good answer.

Comment: What about node.js?